# Replacing arrays access variables with the right integer type

Tags: c, arrays, int, static-analysis, compiler-optimization

I've had a habit of using int to access arrays (especially in for loops); however I recently discovered that I may have been "doing-it-all-wrong" and my x86 system kept hiding the truth from me.  It turns out that int is fine when `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(int)` but when used on a system where `sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(int)`, it causes an additional `mov` instruction.  size_t and ptrdiff_t seem to be the optimal way on the systems I've tested, requiring no additional `mov`.

Here is a shortened example

```
int vector_get(int *v,int i){ return v[i]; }

    > movslq    %esi, %rsi
    > movl  (%rdi,%rsi,4), %eax
    > ret

int vector_get(int *v,size_t i){ return v[i]; }

    > movl  (%rdi,%rsi,4), %eax
    > ret
```

OK, I've fixed myself (using size_t and ptrdiff_t now), now how do I (hopefully not manually) find these instances in my code so I can fix them?

Recently I've noticed several patches including changes from `int` to `size_t` coming across the wire mentioning Clang.

---

I put together a table of the extra instructions that get inserted on each instance to show the results of  "doing-it-all-wrong".

<kbd><kbd><kbd>char</kbd>

            <kbd>short</kbd>

                 <kbd>int</kbd>

    <kbd>unsigned
         char</kbd>

    <kbd>unsigned
        short</kbd>

    <kbd>unsigned
            int</kbd></kbd>
  
  
    <kbd><kbd>movsbq %sil, %rsi</kbd> 

    <kbd>movswq %si, %rsi</kbd>

    <kbd>movslq %esi, %rsi</kbd> 

    
<kbd>movzbl %sil, %esi</kbd>  

    
<kbd>movzwl %si, %esi</kbd>  

    
<kbd>movl %esi, %esi</kbd></kbd>    

  

Table of unwanted move operations when

accessing vectors with "wrong" type.</kbd>

Note: `long`, `long long`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long`, `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` require no additional mov* operation (basically anything >= largest object size, or 8 bytes on the 64 bit reference system )

Edit:

I think I may have a workable stub for patching gcc, but I don't know my way around its source to complete the stub and add proper -Wflag bits, and as usual the hardest part of programming is naming stuff. -Wunalinged-index?

<kbd>gcc/c/c-typeck.c **_______________________________________________**</kbd>

```
if (!swapped)
    warn_array_subscript_with_type_char (index);
> 
> if ( sizeof(index) < sizeof(size_t) ) 
>   warning_at (loc, OPT_Wunaligned_index,
>       "array index is smaller than size_t");

/* Apply default promotions *after* noticing character types.  */
index = default_conversion (index);
```

<kbd>gcc/c-family/c.opt **_____________________________________________**</kbd>

```
trigraphs
C ObjC C++ ObjC++
-trigraphs  Support ISO C trigraphs
> 
> Wunaligned-index
> C ObjC C++ ObjC++
> Warn about array indices smaller than size_t

undef
C ObjC C++ ObjC++ Var(flag_undef)
Do not predefine system-specific and GCC-specific macros
```

<kbd>gcc/c-family/c-opts.c **__________________________________________**</kbd>

```
case OPT_Wtrigraphs:
  cpp_opts->warn_trigraphs = value;
  break;
>
> case OPT_Wunaligned_index:
>   cpp_opts->warn_unaligned_index = value;
>

case OPT_Wundef:
  cpp_opts->warn_undef = value;
  break;
```

Comment: Are you using `int` for the *index*, or what is it that you mean? If the array is larger than `MAXINT`, `int` is indeed wrong. Or do you mean that the array *elements* are larger than `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: In other words, could you give a code example of what you consider wrong access?

Comment: The size of the the array doesn't matter at all, just the sytem's _capability_ of having more than MAXINT elements.  I'll clarify.

Comment: Rather than mess around with MAXINT, I think you could just say that `sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @ecatmur - succinct, I like it.  Fixed.  Added a couple examples too.

Answer (score 1):

clang and gcc have `-Wchar-subscripts`, but that'll only help detect `char` subscript types.

You *might* consider modifying clang or gcc (whichever is easier to build on your infrastructure) to broaden the types detected by the `-Wchar-subscripts` warning. If this is a one-pass fix effort, this might be the most straightforward way to go about it.

Otherwise you'll need to find a linter that complains about non-`size_t`/`ptrdiff_t` subscripting; I'm not aware of any that have that option.

Comment: It seems like -Wchar-subscripts is only concerned about the signedness, but you may be onto something.  If its already looking at the array subscript then it would just need a check `if (sizeof(_subscript_)<sizeof(size_t)) #warn ....`

Answer (score 0):

The `movslq` instruction sign-extends a `long` (aka 4-byte quantity) to a `quad` (aka 8-byte quantity). This is because `int` is signed, so an offset of i.e. `-1` is `0xffffffff` as a long. If you were to just zero-extend that (i.e. not have `movslq`), this would be `0x00000000ffffffff`, aka `4294967295`, which is probably not what you want. So, the compiler instead *sign*-extends the index to yield `0xffff...`, aka `-1`.

The reason the other types don't require the additional operation is because, despite some of them being signed, they're still the same size of 8 bytes. And, thanks to two's complement, `0xffff...` can be interpreted as either `-1` or `18446744073709551615`, and the 64-bit sum will still be the same.

Now, normally, if you were to instead use `unsigned int`, the compiler would *normally* have to insert a *zero*-extend instead, just to make sure the upper-half of the register doesn't contain garbage. However, on the x64 platform, this is done implicitly; an instruction such as `mov %eax,%esi` will move whatever 4-byte quantity is in `eax` into the lower 4 bytes of `rsi` and clear the upper 4, effectively zero-extending the quantity. But, given your postings, the compiler seems to insert `mov %esi,%esi` instruction anyway, "just to be sure".

Note, however, that this "automatic zero-extending" is *not* the case for 1- and 2-byte quantities - those must be manually zero-extended.