# What kind of C11 data type is an array according to the AMD64 ABI

Tags: c, assembly, types, x86-64, calling-convention

I was researching the calling convention of x86_64 that's used on OSX and was reading the section called "Aggregates and Unions" in [the System V x86-64 ABI standard](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf)). It mention arrays and I figured that was like a fixed length c array, e.g. `int[5]`.

I went down to "3.2.3 Parameter Passing" to read about how arrays were passed and if I'm understanding correctly, something like `uint8_t[3]` should be passed in registers as it's smaller than the four eightbyte limit imposed by rule 1 of the classification of aggregate types (page 18 near the bottom).

After compiling I see that instead it's being passed as a pointer.  (I'm compiling with clang-703.0.31 from Xcode 7.3.1 on OSX 10.11.6).

The example source I was using to compile is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define type char

extern void doit(const type[3]);
extern void doitt(const type[5]);
extern void doittt(const type[16]);
extern void doitttt(const type[32]);
extern void doittttt(const type[40]);

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  const char a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
  const char b[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
  const char c[16] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
  const char d[32] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
  const char e[40] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

  doit(a);
  doitt(b);
  doittt(c);
  doitttt(d);
  doittttt(e);
}
```

I dump that in a file named `a.c` and use the following command to compile: `clang -c a.c -o a.o`. I use otool to analyze the assembly generated (by running `otool -tV a.o`) and get the following output:

```
a.o:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000000000000    pushq   %rbp
0000000000000001    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000000000004    subq    $0x10, %rsp
0000000000000008    leaq    _main.a(%rip), %rax
000000000000000f    movl    %edi, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000000000012    movq    %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
0000000000000016    movq    %rax, %rdi
0000000000000019    callq   _doit
000000000000001e    leaq    _main.b(%rip), %rdi
0000000000000025    callq   _doitt
000000000000002a    leaq    _main.c(%rip), %rdi
0000000000000031    callq   _doittt
0000000000000036    leaq    _main.d(%rip), %rdi
000000000000003d    callq   _doitttt
0000000000000042    leaq    _main.e(%rip), %rdi
0000000000000049    callq   _doittttt
000000000000004e    xorl    %eax, %eax
0000000000000050    addq    $0x10, %rsp
0000000000000054    popq    %rbp
0000000000000055    retq
```

Or equivalently, here it is on the [Godbolt compiler explorer with clang3.7](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang37x,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-fverbose-asm',sourcez:MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4DOAXOID2A6ACwD4AoE4RAM3GQwE8AHZCAgQwCcyEAPDBdsEgBuOEHCRxRGABQQcYTEnpMA2gGYAugEoA3CR58Bw0eMkgMMuQoxLGCFQFZteg/0EixEqRdnzFy%2BwBGADZnfV43Y08zCx8rfzt1ACYw1yMPU29Y32tbVQAWAAYwknAbAFtWcGkypA4AcwgAGiR4mxYOJAAqBqEVbSQAbxIkVr92tnY69Q0kAF4hpECWpJa1JABfPVG21smkACNHWYXBpZW1lvyWh03tsdyOqYgVEJPF5aRVpDUrm5bgi0AOwtAAcLQAnC1AoVoZ94dDEUs7iMHoonhJku8zp9vr8kNckA4AcCwZDobClgjzjTqbjLgT/khAUgQUhwUgoUtKYE6Uj4SiduM9p17EVsTS8X8iSTWWTORS4fzlbSLj9pcTmaT2eTuUrVQa%2BYaVYEUaiYtJWLpzd5pAdraMYnEHV5zNk4C6ndkENaNkAAA)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3), which targets Linux which uses the same ABI.

---

So, I was wondering if anyone could lead me to what data types in C11 apply to arrays.  (It looks like clang defaults to using C11 - see the blurb [here](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html) right under C99 inline function).

I also did a similar investigation with ARM and found similar results, even though **the [ARM standard](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0042f/IHI0042F_aapcs.pdf) also specifies there exists an array aggregate type**.

Also, is there somewhere in some standard that it's specified that a fixed length array is to be treated as a pointer?

Comment: @PeterCordes: Arrays decay to pointers in most but not all contexts. More to the point, C does not permit parameters of array type. In a declaration like `void func(int param[]);`, the type of `param` is **adjusted** from `int[]` to `int*`. (This is a distinct rule from the one that specifies implicit conversion of array expressions to pointers.)

Comment: @PeterCordes so is there no data type in c11 or c99 that is considered an array as defined in the x86_64/arm standards?

Comment: @KeithThompson do you have a reference for the fact that C does not permit parameters of array type? I'd love to read more!

Comment: @KeithThompson: ok, after a couple mis-steps with terminology, I think my answer mostly avoids any incorrect statements.  Is "decay" the wrong word to describe the fact that array args to functions are always passed as pointers?  I guess multi-dimensional arrays are still arrays.

Comment: @DanZimm: C certainly has arrays, and I presume they correspond to "arrays" as defined in the x64_64/arm standards. Reference: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.7.6.3 paragraph 7.

Comment: @PeterCordes: "Decay" is a commonly used term, though the standard doesn't call it that; it merely says it's "converted". Note that decay is not specific to function arguments. An array expression is implicitly converted to a pointer in all but 3 contexts (`sizeof`, `&`, and a string literal in an initializer used to initialize an array object); argument passing just happens to be one of the contexts where the conversion does happen.

Comment: @KeithThompson Do you have the reference about the pointer not being converted in those 3 contexts? I want to make sure I understand exactly what you mean (I understand the sizeof, but I'm interested in reading more about the `&`, string literal in an initializer). EDIT: Didnt see your response to me above - apologies. It looks like that fact you stated is just known because you're very familiar with the standard based on how 6.7.6.3 paragraph 7 is worded.

Comment: @DanZimm: [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.3.2.1 paragraph 3. (The reference to `_Alignof` is incorrect in that draft, corrected in the published ISO C11 standard.)

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks for the references!! Fwiw it looks like array isn't used in the same sense in the ABIs I linked to as they're used in the C standard (in the ABIs an array isn't ever "converted" or treated as a pointer - it's always its own sort of data, either an aggregate or a composite depending which ABI you're looking at)

Comment: @DanZimm: Arrays are not *treated* as pointers in C; arrays and pointers are two distinct kinds of types. Array expressions are sometimes *converted* to pointers -- but that's probably not something that an ABI needs to concern itself with.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm sorry I'm not being as precise with my terminology - arrays in the C standard are not directly equivalent to arrays in the ABI. In the C standard it's dealing with a kind of type, while the ABI is talking about kinds of data, or so it seems. Again, my terminology may not be as precise as it could be but I think the point I'm trying to make is clear: arrays as defined in the C standard don't map directly to arrays in the ABIs

Comment: @KeithThompson eesh that last comment came off much more aggressively than I meant it to, sorry about that :/. Anyways, thanks for the references and information you provided!

Comment: @DanZimm: No problem. Actually I just took a quick look at the ABI document you cited, and I think that its use of the word "array" is consistent with the way C (and C++) uses the term. C defines certain *operations* on arrays oddly, but in particular I think array *objects* are the same in C and in the ABI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Bare** arrays as function args in C and C++ *always* decay to pointers, just like in several other contexts.

Arrays inside `struct`s or `union`s don't, and are passed by value.  This is why ABIs need to care about how they're passed, even though it doesn't happen in C for bare arrays.

---

As [Keith Thomson points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800044/what-kind-of-c11-data-type-is-an-array-according-to-the-amd64-abi?noredirect=1#comment64984850_38800044), the relevant part of the C standard is [N1570 section 6.7.6.3 paragraph 7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=151)

> A declaration of a parameter as "array of type" shall be adjusted to
> "qualified pointer to type", where the type qualifiers (if any) are
> those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation ... *(stuff about `foo[static 10]`, see below)*

Note that multidimensional arrays work as arrays of array type, so only the outer-most level of "array-ness" is converted to a pointer to array type.

---

Terminology:  The x86-64 ABI doc uses the same terminology as ARM, where `struct`s and arrays are "aggregates" (multiple elements at sequential addresses).  So the phrase "aggregates and unions" comes up a lot, because `union`s are handled similarly by the language and the ABI.

It's the recursive rule for handling composite types (struct/union/class) that brings the array-passing rules in the ABI into play.  **This is the only way you'll see asm that copies an array to the stack as part of a function arg, for C or C++**

```
struct s { int a[8]; };
void ext(struct s byval);

void foo() { struct s tmp = {{0}}; ext(tmp); }
```

[gcc6.1 compiles it (for the AMD64 SysV ABI, with `-O3`)](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:%27-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-fverbose-asm%27,source:%27struct+s+%7B+int+a%5B8%5D%3B+%7D%3B%0Avoid+ext(struct+s+byval)%3B%0A%0Avoid+foo()+%7B+struct+s+tmp+%3D+%7B%7B0%7D%7D%3B+ext(tmp)%3B+%7D%0A%27)),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3) to the following:

```
    sub     rsp, 40    # align the stack and leave room for `tmp` even though it's never stored?
    push    0
    push    0
    push    0
    push    0
    call    ext
    add     rsp, 72
    ret
```

---

In the x86-64 ABI, pass-by-value happens by actual copying (into registers or the stack), not by hidden pointers.

Note that return-by-value does pass a pointer as a "hidden" first arg (in `rdi`), when the return value is too large to fit in the 128bit concatenation of `rdx:rax` (and isn't a vector being returned in vector regs, etc. etc.)

It would be possible for the ABI to use a hidden pointer to pass-by-value objects above a certain size, and trust the called function not to modify the original, but that's not what the x86-64 ABI chooses to do.  That would be better in some cases (especially for inefficient C++ with lots of copying without modification (i.e. wasted)), but worse in other cases.

**SysV ABI bonus reading**: As the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki points out, the current version of the ABI standard doesn't fully document the behaviour that compilers rely on: [clang/gcc sign/zero extend narrow args to 32bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for/36760539#36760539).

---

Note that to really guarantee that a function arg is a fixed-size array, **[C99 and later lets you use the `static` keyword in a new way](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/keyword/static)**: on array sizes.  (It's still passed as a pointer, of course.  This doesn't change the ABI).

```
void bar(int arr[static 10]);
```

This allows compiler warnings about going out of bounds.  It also potentially enables better optimization if the compiler knows it's allowed to access elements that the C source doesn't.  (See [this blog post](https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2013-02-18-static-array-indices.html)).  However, the arg still has type `int*`, not an actual array, so `sizeof(arr) == sizeof(int*)`.

[The same keyword page for C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static) indicates that ISO C++ does not support this usage of `static`; it's another one of those C-only features, along with C99 variable-length-arrays and a few other goodies that C++ doesn't have.

In C++, you can use [`std::array<int,10>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to get compile-time size information passed to the caller.  However, you have to manually pass it by reference if that's what you want, since it's of course just a class containing an `int arr[10]`.  *Unlike a C-style array, it doesn't decay to `T*` automatically.*

---

**The ARM doc that you linked** doesn't seem to actually call arrays an aggregate type:  *Section 4.3 Composite Types* (which discusses alignment) distinguishes arrays from aggregate types, even though they appear to be a special case of its definition for aggregates.

> A Composite Type is a collection of one or more Fundamental Data Types that are handled as a single entity at the
> procedure call level. A Composite Type can be any of:
>
> - An aggregate, where the members are laid out sequentially in memory
> - A union, where each of the members has the same address
> - An array, which is a repeated sequence of some other type (its base type).
>
> The definitions are recursive; that is, each of the types may contain a Composite Type as a member

"Composite" is an umbrella term that includes arrays, structs, and unions.

Comment: The x86-84 ABI doc also calls `array`s aggregates as well: `The classification of aggregate (structures and arrays) and union types works as follows:` so shouldn't it be that `array`s (as define by the ABI) should be able to be passed by value as well? P.S. Thanks for the detailed answer, especially the piece on the static keyword - I never knew that!

Comment: @DanZimm: crap, you're right.  I didn't double check the terminology, since I was (and still am) 100% sure I'm correct about what actually happens to C array args: they're passed as pointers.  Perhaps other languages allow pass-by-value of arrays?  There's a Fortran section in the ABI doc.

Comment: Maybe Rust/Swift can take advantage of this? I don't have the clang source on this computer so I don't remember where, but passing arrays by value seems to be implemented in the underlying compiler (I think my terminology is wrong, but I saw code that properly maps an array onto register/into the stack by value instead of by pointer).

Comment: @DanZimm: That would make sense for passing an array inside a struct.  In that case, it's part of an aggregate that's passed by value according to C's rules, so it does get copied to regs / stack .

Comment: @DanZimm: Ok, thanks for catching my errors in terminology.  I think I have this answer cleaned up into something that's useful and error-free.  I'm open to suggestions for what else would be useful to say in this answer.  (I guess a language spec citation for the array to pointer decay / conversion in function args would be good, but I don't really want to go dig that up.  It's basically a well-known fact as far as I'm concerned.)

Comment: This:

> This lets sizeof(arr) work as you might expect inside the called function

could be interpreted to mean that `sizeof(arr) == sizeof(int)*10` but it's still `sizeof(int*)` nothing else.

Comment: @björnen: Thanks, fixed that bit of wishful thinking :P