# Why is there a calling convention for arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, x86-64, calling-convention

I am reading the [System V Application Binary Interface](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf), and there is one part that I cannot make sense of.

First, the document states that

> No attempt has been made to specify an ABI for languages other than C

(page 10).

Later, on page 20, arrays are classified as MEMORY, POINTER etc.:

> The classification of aggregate (structures and arrays) and union types works
>   as follows:
>   ...

The classification is then used to define the calling conventions — how the values and bounds on them are passed to and returned from functions. If I am reading the algorithm correctly, an array could be classified as INTEGER, MEMORY, or SSE.

But in the C language, arrays are always passed and returned as pointers. So why is it useful to classify arrays and in which situation does the array class matter?

Comment: The first quote, by itself, is easy to understand because C is the [lingua franca](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_franca) of the Unix world. As for the second quote, that C passes arrays as pointers (or rater let the array decay to a pointer to its first element) is because that's how C worked since the beginning and that's what the C specification says should happen.

Comment: [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800044/what-kind-of-c11-data-type-is-an-array-according-to-the-amd64-abi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: if an array is part of a struct or union, it may be passed in a register.

This C code

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct somebytes {
  uint8_t bytes[8];
};

uint8_t plus(struct somebytes p) {
  return p.bytes[3]+p.bytes[5];
}
```

translates to this assembly:

```
mov    %rdi,%rax
shr    $0x28,%rdi
shr    $0x18,%rax
add    %edi,%eax
retq
```