# Position of Memory parameters on the Stack x86_64 gcc

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention

I am starting with Assembly and, for testing, I've written a simple C program, compiled and disassembled it, in order to see how the parameters are passed. This is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void calc (float*a,float*b,float*c,float*d) {
    a[0]=1000;
    b[0]=100.0;
    c[0]=99.9;
    d[0]=10000;
}


int main() {
    float a[100];
    float b[100];
    float c[100];
    float d[100];
    calc(a,b,c,d);
}
```

And this is its disassembly:

```
default rel

global calc: function
global main: function


SECTION .text   align=1 execute                         ; section number 1, code

calc:   ; Function begin
        push    rbp                                     ; 0000 _ 55
        mov     rbp, rsp                                ; 0001 _ 48: 89. E5
        mov     qword [rbp-8H], rdi                     ; 0004 _ 48: 89. 7D, F8
        mov     qword [rbp-10H], rsi                    ; 0008 _ 48: 89. 75, F0
        mov     qword [rbp-18H], rdx                    ; 000C _ 48: 89. 55, E8
        mov     qword [rbp-20H], rcx                    ; 0010 _ 48: 89. 4D, E0
                   ; 0054 _ 90
        pop     rbp                                     ; 0055 _ 5D
        ret                                             ; 0056 _ C3
; calc End of function

main:   ; Function begin
        push    rbp                                     ; 0057 _ 55
        mov     rbp, rsp                                ; 0058 _ 48: 89. E5
        sub     rsp, 1600                               ; 005B _ 48: 81. EC, 00000640
        lea     rcx, [rbp-640H]                         ; 0062 _ 48: 8D. 8D, FFFFF9C0
        lea     rdx, [rbp-4B0H]                         ; 0069 _ 48: 8D. 95, FFFFFB50
        lea     rsi, [rbp-320H]                         ; 0070 _ 48: 8D. B5, FFFFFCE0
        lea     rax, [rbp-190H]                         ; 0077 _ 48: 8D. 85, FFFFFE70
        mov     rdi, rax                                ; 007E _ 48: 89. C7
        call    calc                                    ; 0081 _ E8, 00000000(rel)
        mov     eax, 0                                  ; 0086 _ B8, 00000000
        leave                                           ; 008B _ C9
        ret                                             ; 008C _ C3
; main End of function
```

I don't understand why the parameters on the stack are of differing size. The first one is in `[ebp-8H]`, which is understandable, as it is a 64-bit address, but the next one is only two bytes further, in `[ebp-10H]` instead of `[ebp-16H]`.
Why is that, and, most importantly, when I write an assembler procedure that takes these exact parameters, which addresses should I use from `ebp`?

Comment: [64 bit uses registers to pass arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI). What you are seeing in memory is not the arguments, they are temporary local variables which look silly because you didn't enable optimization. Layout of locals is entirely up to the compiler (or the programmer). PS: `10H` is 16 decimal so it's not 2 bytes from `8H`.

Comment: Do you know about hexadecimal ?

Comment: By the way, [x86 calling convention on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI). Has relevant source material at bottom as well. Most notably, [ABI-IA64.pdf](http://chamilo2.grenet.fr/inp/courses/ENSIMAG3MM1LDB/document/doc_abi_ia64.pdf)

Comment: _"Apart from the funny bit that it stores all the parameters first to registers"_ You've just derided tenths of years of convention. I find nothing funny in it. There are _very_ good reasons to do that.

Comment: @Jester , AFAIK memory parameters are passed on the stack, and Integer parameters in registers. I am pretty sure the content of `ebp-8H` until `ebp-20H` are the parameters, as they are used as adresses to store the modified values. PS: You are completely right, of course.

Comment: @drilow> please have  alook at the pdf I linked in me previous comment, ABI-IA64. It describes everything you have to know about interfacing C code and assembly. There is much more to it than just where the parameters go. You must know which registers must be preserved across calls, whether there are permanently fixed registers, ...

Comment: "ebp-8H until ebp-20H are the parameters" they are temporary locals that hold a copy of the parameters because the code moves them from registers to memory. You know that intel syntax is `mov destination, source` right?

Comment: Ok, my fault about the hexadecimal, of course. @spectras, I will indeed look at that.

Comment: @Jester I will definetly think a bit longer before posting next time. Thanks for the quick answers anyway!

Comment: There is no such thing as a "memory parameter". If you mean an *address*, then that's just an integer, and it's passed in an integer register.

Comment: @Cody Gray I mean a memory parameter as portrayed in the AMD Documentation referenced by spectras

Comment: A pointer value counts as an integer parameter in the ABI.  If you were passing `struct { float a[100]; }` by value, then it would be copied into memory on the stack.  But plain arrays decay to pointers.  See [What kind of C11 data type is an array according to the AMD64 ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800044/what-kind-of-c11-data-type-is-an-array-according-to-the-amd64-abi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like I say this a lot, but presumably you haven't heard it yet, so it bears repeating: analyzing the disassembly of *unoptimized* code is largely a waste of time. When optimizations are disabled, compilers are focused on two things:

1. Generating code as quickly as possible, so you get the fastest possible compiles, and
2. Making it easy for you to debug the code (for example, by ensuring that you can set a breakpoint on each high-level language statement, and by not reordering instructions to allow you to step through the code).

Unoptimized code is messy, ugly, and confusing. It contains a lot of redundant instructions, doesn't look like what a human being would write, and doesn't match the code found in real-world applications (which are compiled with optimizations enabled).

When you want to analyze assembly code, turn on the optimizer.

When we do so, we see that your code compiles to:

```
calc(float*, float*, float*, float*):
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], 0x447a0000
    mov     DWORD PTR [rsi], 0x42c80000
    mov     DWORD PTR [rdx], 0x42c7cccd
    mov     DWORD PTR [rcx], 0x461c4000
    ret

main:
    xor     eax, eax
    ret
```

Wait, what happened? Well, the optimizer saw that `main` doesn't *do* anything except return 0 (implicitly; not even represented in your code), so it transformed the entire function to simply an instruction that clears the `EAX` register and then returns.

From this, though, we can tell that a function's result is returned in `EAX`. This is true in the System V AMD64 calling convention common on Unix systems, and it's also true in the 64-bit calling convention used on Windows, and it's even true across all 32-bit x86 calling conventions that you'll find in the wild. (32-bit results are returned in `EAX`; 64-bit results are returned in `EDX:EAX`, where the high-order bits are in `EDX` and the low-order bits are in `EAX`.)

We can also tell by looking at the `calc` function's disassembly how it receives its parameters. The first integer parameter is passed in `RDI`, the second in `RSI`, the third in `RDX`, and the fourth in `RCX`. As per the System V AMD64 calling convention, if there was a fifth parameter, it would be passed in `R8`, and the sixth parameter would be passed in `R9`.

In other words, up to the first six integer parameters are passed in registers. After that, any additional integer parameters are passed on the stack.

Floating-point parameters are passed in XMM registers (`XMM0` through `XMM7`), to facilitate use of SSE instructions. Again, any additional floating-point parameters are passed on the stack.

You try to make a distinction in the comments between "integer parameters" and "memory parameters", but there is no such thing as the latter. When you pass pointers (or references in C++, which compilers implement in terms of pointers), you are actually passing *addresses*. Since addresses are just integers, they are passed just like any other integer value—in registers.

If you pass parameters on the stack, they are all 8 bytes (64 bits) in size, and come one after the other. The first one is at an offset of 8 from the stack pointer, `RBP`. The second one would be at an offset of 16, etc. There seemed to be a bit of confusion when you were looking at the code in the question that arose from the offsets being represented in *hexadecimal*, where `10h` is equivalent to 16 in decimal, and `18h` is equivalent to 24 in decimal. (Why does the first parameter start at an offset of 8? Because the first position, `RBP+0`, is occupied by the return pointer.)

This basically covers the fundamentals of the calling convention. But frankly, analyzing disassembly is *not* a very good way of learning calling conventions. There are a lot more details that you won't necessarily see, and you won't get the big picture view. You really need to [read the fine manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf). If you hate manuals, there are more concise (and more simplified) summaries available various places online, e.g., [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

Comment: `-O0` is worse than just not reordering.  It spills everything to memory between C statements (or between source lines?) so *modifying* a variable with the debugger will have the expected results.  This requires it to be horribly inefficient.

Comment: related: The ABI defines how to pass arrays by value because of cases like passing `struct { float a[100]; }` by value.  See [What kind of C11 data type is an array according to the AMD64 ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800044/what-kind-of-c11-data-type-is-an-array-according-to-the-amd64-abi).  I think the OP was thinking of arrays as "large objects" that wouldn't fit in registers, and missed that arrays decay to pointers in C.