# Why does reading EOF make scanf return 4294967295?

Tags: assembly, scanf, x86-64

In my assembly program I want to test that standard input reached its EOF

```
segment .data
    .fmt_read db "%80s", 0 ; 79 bytes of actual string + terminating 0

segment .text
    lea rdi, [.fmt_read]
    lea rsi, [buf_str]     ; buffer to fill in
    xor eax, eax           ; no floating-point parameters are passed
    call scanf
    cmp rax, -1            ; did we reach EOF(-1)
    je .done               ; yes? End the program
```

When I debug it in gdb I press *Ctrl-D* to make the scanf recognise EOF.
Then test return value in rax, hoping to find an EOF indicator(-1).

```
(gdb) p $rax
$5 = 4294967295
(gdb) p/x $rax
$6 = 0xffffffff
```

I understand that it is the value -1 in binary two's complement.
Although, I did not understand why `cmp rax, -1` did not set ZF(as they are equal).

How to determine EOF?

Comment: 64-bit -1 would be `0xffffffffffffffff`

Comment: Zapping EAX on entry and testing RAX on return - intentional?

Comment: @Tom, yes, I explained it in code comments.

Comment: @TomGoodfellow: RAX as an input is totally separate from RAX as an output.  On input, the x86-64 SysV ABI requires AL=number of FP args in XMM regs for variadic functions.  Also, perhaps you weren't aware of that `xor eax,eax` does zero RAX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no `CMP r/m64, imm64` (or `CMP RAX, imm64`). There's `CMP RAX, imm32` which sign-extends the immediate operand to 64 bits, i.e. `-1` (`0xffffffff`) will be sign-extended to `0xffffffffffffffff`.

If you want to compare `RAX` to `0xffffffff` you can use something like:

```
mov ebx, -1
cmp rax, rbx
```

Or you could simply use `EAX` in the comparison rather than `RAX`:

```
cmp eax, -1
```

Comment: but why scanf returned 0xffffffff(32 bit) in rax and not 0xffffffffffffffff(64 bit) on amd64 machine?
I read man on Linux 64 bit machine and it does not mention limit of return value or its size. Do you have any clues?

Comment: @BulatM. : because [scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) returns a 32-bit `int` not a 64-bit `long` on 64-bit Linux. So you need to rely on the data in the lower 32-bits of _RAX_ .

Comment: @BulatM.: That would depend on the size of `int`, and exactly how `EOF` is defined. There's a function named `feof` that returns non-zero if EOF has been reached for a given file. It might be a better idea to use that rather than checking for EOF directly.

Comment: @Michael: Now I understand, one little question: where did you find that scanf returns 32-bit int? I searched in several man pages and did find no mention of it. Maybe it is mentioned in POSIX specifications?
And why depends not on long(on 64-bit machines, that would be logical) but on int?

Comment: @BulatM. It is platform dependent as to what `int` is. But 64-bit Linux defines `int` as a 32-bit value. You can see a chart like the one [here](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-11-sect-1)

Comment: @BulatM.: Why would you ever want scanf to be able to convert more than 2^31-1 args in one call?  Using a less efficient wider integer (`long`) makes no sense.  In any case, ISO C (not POSIX) defines scanf as returning an `int`, not a `long`.  Both can be as small as 16-bit.  If 64-bit registers were faster or led to smaller code-size, x86-64 ABIs might have chosen to make `int` a 64-bit type.  In general, they're the same speed, except that 64-bit takes larger machine code (a REX prefix), so 32-bit ops are the most efficient.

Comment: `If you want to compare RAX to 0xffffffff` but don't do that, because the ABI doesn't require 32-bit return values to be zero or sign extended to 64-bits.  The upper bits of RAX should be assumed to contain random garbage, for any width or return value less than 64 bits.  (function arg-passing is similar, but [narrow args are sign or zero extended to 32-bit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for/36760539#36760539) in the x86-64 SysV ABI)

Comment: @Peter, and what is the correct way to do that(compare lower rax part to -1)? Should use `cmp eax, -1`?

Comment: @BulatM.: yes, of course.  Just look at C compiler output to see what happens when you do the equivalent thing in C.  Write a quick function on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ or something.