# Why does gcc perform tail call optimization for one version but not for the other?

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, tail-call-optimization

Experimenting with tail call optimization (tco), I stumbled upon the following curious example:

```
unsigned long long int fac1(unsigned long long int n){
  if (n==0)
    return 1;
  return n*fac1(n-1);
}
```

actually, I was impressed, that [gcc was able](https://godbolt.org/g/YqxYRA) to perform the tco here (with `-O2` flag), because it is not that straight forward:

```
fac1(unsigned long long):
        testq   %rdi, %rdi
        movl    $1, %eax
        je      .L4
.L3:
        imulq   %rdi, %rax
        subq    $1, %rdi
        jne     .L3
        rep ret
.L4:
        rep ret
```

However, after the change of the return type from `unsigned long long int` to `unsigned int` gcc was not able to perform tlo:

```
unsigned int fac2(unsigned long long int n){
  if (n==0)
    return 1;
  return n*fac2(n-1);
}
```

we can clearly see the recursive call in the [resulting assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/YqxYRA):

```
fac2(unsigned long long):
        testq   %rdi, %rdi
        jne     .L16
        movl    $1, %eax
        ret
.L16:
        pushq   %rbx
        movq    %rdi, %rbx
        leaq    -1(%rdi), %rdi
        call    fac2(unsigned long long)
        imull   %ebx, %eax
        popq    %rbx
        ret
```

At first, I dismissed this as a missed optimization, but now I'm not that sure, because [clang isn't able](https://godbolt.org/g/kB2mKD) to perform this optimization as well. So maybe there are subtlities of the language I'm not aware of which prevent this optimization.

Why doesn't gcc perform the tail-call-optimization for the function `fac2` but only for `fac1`?

---

It is clear to me, that in the second version, the result must be downcasted. Obviously this is the only difference. But why should this be a problem and prevent tlo?

For example, if I help the compiler and rewrite my function as a classic tail-recursion (which should produce identical results to version `fac2`):

```
unsigned int tlo_fac(unsigned long long int n, unsigned long long int cur){
  if (n==0)
    return cur;
  return tlo_fac(n-1, n*cur);
}

unsigned int fac(unsigned long long int n){
  return tlo_fac(n,1);
}
```

I get a tlo-optimized version which is  [identical to `fac1`](https://godbolt.org/g/kfn8oc) (the high 32bit are [allowed to contain garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760539/5769463), so `imulq` can be used after inlining):

```
fac(unsigned long long):
        testq   %rdi, %rdi
        movl    $1, %eax
        je      .L10
.L11:
        imulq   %rdi, %rax
        subq    $1, %rdi
        jne     .L11
.L10:
        rep ret
```

Comment: May be because there is cast needed in `return n*fac2(n-1);` after call to `fact2(n-1)`

Comment: @GauravSehgal but why would this cast prevent tlo?

Comment: Because cast will be performed after the recursion depth is analyzed.If you change the parameter to `fact2(unisnged int n)`, you will get the optimization.

Answer (score 2):

In `fact2()`, after recursion is completed a cast will be needed from `unsigned long long int` to `unsigned int`

`unsigned int fac2(unsigned int n)` produces the below assembly,

```
fac2(unsigned int):
        testl   %edi, %edi
        movl    $1, %eax
        je      .L10
.L9:
        imull   %edi, %eax
        subl    $1, %edi
        jne     .L9
        rep ret
.L10:
        rep ret
```

Comment: This may confuse GCC, but it does not *fundamentally* prevent rewriting it to iteration

Comment: I'm aware, that a cast is needed and also that changing input parameter type to the output type would lead to a tlo'ed version. But it is not clear to me, why this would prevent TLO.

Comment: @ead To perform tail call optimization, the recursive call should be the last thing to be done from the function, `return n*fac1(n-1);`, the last thing is not the function call `fact(n-1)`, but the casting of result.

Comment: actually, the order is: recur-call, multiplication, casting. So even without casting the recur-call is not the last thing done in the function (and this is the part which impressed me in the first place)