# What's a good way to assign to a bit with a specific index?

Tags: assembly, optimization, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, micro-optimization

This question:

[How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit)

discusses three operations on a specific bit within a larger value, which correspond in a straightforward manner to OR 1, AND 0, and XOR 1 on that bit. But what if we don't know that second bit's value in advance? What if we want perform an *assignment*, where we don't know the other operand bit at compile-time? That is, we want set one bit, at a certain position a bit block,  to the value of a new unrelated bit provided at run-time?

I'd like to have the fastest possible implementation for this on,  say, Intel x86_64 (and ignoring vectorization, which I hope is irrelevant here). Also, suppose for simplicity the bit block type is `uint32_t`.

**Edit:** Made my answer C rather than C++, since there's nothing C++'ish about the question really.

Comment: @fuz: No, otherwise it would have been just a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible implementations, for the case of a 32-bit block type:

```
#include <cstdint>

uint32_t bit_assign_v1(uint32_t block, uint8_t bit_index, bool x)
{
    uint32_t mask = uint32_t { 1 } << bit_index;
    return (block & ~mask) | (((uint32_t) x) << bit_index);
}

uint32_t bit_assign_v2(uint32_t block, uint8_t bit_index, bool x)
{
    uint32_t mask = uint32_t { 1 } << bit_index;
    return x ? (block & ~mask) : (block | mask);
}
```

Using GodBolt, I get differently-optimized code for each of these two options, which also differs as we change the platforms, and compilers. Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/at_Cfj) for Skylake (or better yet, look at [this version](https://godbolt.org/z/fV6mLA), which is the same code but split into more C statements so you can better associate the assembly with the C code).

GCC 8.2 assembly:

```
bit_assign_1:
        movzx   eax, sil
        btr     edi, eax
        movzx   edx, dl
        shlx    eax, edx, eax
        or      eax, edi
        ret
bit_assign_2:
        mov     ecx, 1
        shlx    esi, ecx, esi
        andn    eax, esi, edi
        or      esi, edi
        test    dl, dl
        cmove   eax, esi
        ret
```

clang 7.0 assembly:

```
bit_assign_1:                           # @bit_assign_1
        btr     edi, esi
        shlx    eax, edx, esi
        or      eax, edi
        ret
bit_assign_2:                           # @bit_assign_2
        mov     eax, edi
        btr     eax, esi
        bts     edi, esi
        test    edx, edx
        cmovne  edi, eax
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

I haven't benchmarked any of this yet.

Comment: This is not an assignment though

Comment: The first asm looks better for throughput on Intel: only 5 uops, vs. 6 (or 7 on Haswell and earlier where cmov is 2).  But on Ryzen, `btr` costs 2 uops.  (The `movzx eax, sil` is redundant, though.  `btr` masks the count so `btr edi, esi` would ignore the low bits.  Hopefully that disappears when inlining, though.  In the 2nd version, the `mov ecx,1` could be hoisted out of a loop, and the `test dl,dl` could disappear (flags set by whatever computed the result).

Comment: I wonder if you could get gcc or clang to emit `btr`, `mov+bts`, and `test`/`cmov` to select the reset or set version?  The choice between these versions might depend on which of the 3 inputs is on the critical path for latency.  The first version has 3c latency from `bool x` being ready to the result being ready, but the 2nd only has 2c latency there (with single-uop `cmov`.)  The first would also be 2 uops if gcc knew to use a different register for `movzx` to allow mov-elimination, though :/  But if movzx optimizes away on inlining...

Comment: @Slava: Well, these functions return the result of the assignment, so it's good enough...

Comment: @PeterCordes: About your second comment - see edit for what clang does bt default. I'm not very fluent in assembly (e.g. I need to read up on `btr`). I will say though that, in a loop, you very often need to assign to _many_ bits of the same byte, and if you know what the pattern of assignment positions are you may be able to do something smarter still.

Comment: `btr` Resets (clears) the destination bit selected by the source index.  The manual for `bt`/`btr`/`bts`/`btc` http://felixcloutier.com/x86/BTR.html isn't 100% clear that the shift-count is masked for register counts.  But it is, and I think gcc knows this.  Or maybe just clang does. (I've seen one of them optimize away the AND in `x & (1<< (n&31))`).

Comment: Note that the clang version is dependent on the unwritten "guarantee" that narrow inputs are zero- or sign-extended to 32 bit by the caller.  That's why it can leave out both `movzx` instructions.  [Is a sign or zero extension required when adding a 32bit offset to a pointer for the x86-64 ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36760539).  Neat, clang uses my other idea :P  But yeah, only 3 uops is very nice.  I don't think you can do better than that, and unfortunately x86 doesn't have a `btx` exchange instruction that copies CF *into* to destination, only unconditional set, reset, and complement.

Comment: @PeterCordes: So, just so I get this straight - clang is relying on the top bytes of `%esi` being 0, even though the ABI doesn't guarantee that they are? Cuh-razeee!

Comment: Yup, read the linked answer.  Both gcc and clang do satisfy that not-yet-standardized behaviour when emitting code that calls functions, but only clang relies on it in the callee.  I forget if ICC can safely call clang code or not, but gcc and clang can call each other.  Hand-written asm calling clang code could also be a problem.