# Does RISC-V prefer to sign-extend 8-bit operands?

Tags: riscv

On 64-bit RISC-V, when a 32-bit operand is loaded into a register, it is necessary to decide whether to sign-extend or zero-extend to 64 bits, and the architectural decision was made to prefer the former, presumably on the grounds that the most common `int` type in C family languages is a signed 32-bit integer. So sign extension is slightly faster than zero extension.

Is the same true of 8-bit operands? In other words, is `signed char` more efficient than `unsigned char`?

Comment: What do you mean by more efficient? Do you mean the sign extension of 8-bit to a higher bit representation or just more general efficiencies between signed and unsigned chars. For the latter I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712315/performance-of-unsigned-vs-signed-integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re going to be widening a lot of 8-bit values to `wchar_t`, `unsigned char` is what you want, because that’s a no-op rather than a bitmask.  If your `char` format is UTF-8, you also want to be able to use unsigned math for your shifts.  If you’re using library functions, it’s most convenient to use the types your library expects.

[The RISC-V architecture has](https://riscv.org/wp-content/plugins/pdf-viewer/stable/web/viewer.html?file=https://content.riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/riscv-spec.pdf#section.2.6) both a `LB` instruction that loads a sign-extended 8-bit value into a register, and a `LBU` instruction that zero-extends.  Both are equally efficient.  In C, any `signed char` used in an arithmetic operation is widened to `int`, and the C standard library functions specify widening `char` to `int`, so this puts the variable in the correct format to use.

Storing is a matter of truncation, and converting from any integral type to `unsigned char` is trivial (bitmask by `0xff`). Converting from an `unsigned char` to a signed value can be done in no more than two instructions, without conditionals or register pressure (`SLLI` to put the sign bit of the `char` into the sign bit of the machine register, followed by `SRLI` to sign-extend the upper bits).

There is therefore no additional overhead in this architecture to working with either.  The API specifies sign-extension rather than zero-extension of signed quantities.

Incidentally, RV64I does not architecturally prefer sign-extension.  That is [the ABI convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654359/4474419), but the instruction set adds a `LWU` instruction to load a 32-bit value from memory with zero-extension and an `ADDIW` that can sign-extend a zero-extended 32-bit result.  (There is no corresponding `ADDIB` for 8-bit or `ADDIH` for 16-bit quantities.)