# Integer describing number of floating point arguments in xmm registers not passed to rax

Tags: linux, macos, assembly, nasm, x86-64

I have got a function which is declared as follows:

```
double foo(int ** buffer, int size, ...);
```

The function is a part of cpp implementation of a program.

I use last parameter to pass multiple double variables to the function.

The problem is that on Mac I do not receive valid number in rax register, on the other hand on ubuntu it works as expected.

A simple example:

**CPP**

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" double foo(int ** buffer, int buffer_size, ...);

int main() {
    int* buffer [] = {new int(2), new int(3), new int(4)};
    std::cout<< foo(buffer, 2, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0) << '\n';
    std::cout<< foo(buffer, 3, 2.0, 3.0) << '\n';
    std::cout<< foo(buffer, 3) << '\n';
}
```

**Assembly, NASM2**

```
global foo

section .text

foo:
    cvtsi2sd xmm0, rax
    ret
```

Mac output:

```
1.40468e+14
1.40736e+14
1.40736e+14
```

Ubuntu output:

```
3
2
0
```

The program is 64-bit

Comment: Note that this number is stored in `al`, not `rax`.  Try `movzx eax, al` beforehand to clear out the high bits.

Comment: The value was in al

Comment: @MateuszStompór : which is correct. the only part of RAX that matters is AL. The other bits can be anything. As fuz suggested use `movzx eax, al` to make all of RAX equal to the value in AL. It happens to be on Ubuntu the upper bits of RAX were already 0.On your Mac they weren't. Try `foo:`
    `movzx eax, al`
    `cvtsi2sd xmm0, rax`
    `ret` . Should be noted that when the destination of an instruction is a 32-bit register the CPU zero extends automatically across the entire 64-bit register.

Comment: Yes, That exactly was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The x86-64 System V ABI says the FP register arg count is passed in AL, and that the upper bytes of RAX are allowed to contain garbage**.  (Same as any narrow integer or FP arg.  But see also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for/36760539#36760539) about clang assuming zero- or sign-extension of narrow integer args to 32 bit.  This only applies to function args proper, not `al`.)

Use `movzx eax, al` to zero-extend AL into RAX.  (Writing EAX implicitly zero-extends into RAX, unlike writing an 8 or 16-bit register.)

If there's another integer register you can clobber, **use `movzx ecx,al`** so mov-elimination on Intel CPUs can work, making it zero latency and not needing an execution port.  Intel's mov-elimination fails when the src and dst are parts of the same register.

There's also zero benefit to using a 64-bit source for conversion to FP.  `cvtsi2sd xmm0, eax` is one byte shorter (no REX prefix), and after zero-extension into EAX you know that the signed 2's complement interpretation of EAX and RAX that `cvtsi2sd` uses are identical.

---

**On your Mac, clang/LLVM chose to leave garbage in the upper bytes of RAX**.  LLVM's optimizer is less careful about avoiding false dependencies than gcc's, so it will sometimes write partial registers.  (Sometimes even when it doesn't save code size, but in this case it does).

**From your results, we can conclude that you used clang on Mac, and gcc or ICC on Ubuntu.**

It's easier to look at the compiler-generate asm from a simplified example (`new` and `std::cout::operator<<` result in a lot of code).

```
extern "C" double foo(int, ...);
int main() {
    foo(123, 1.0, 2.0);
}
```

Compiles to this asm on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:1.2899450879999999,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'extern+%22C%22+double+foo(int,+...)%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++foo(123,+1.0,+2.0)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:36.66505163050122,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:31.528037574377116,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-Wextra+-O3+-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-mtune%3Dskylake',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:31.806910795121674,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), with gcc and clang -O3:

```
### clang7.0 -O3
.section .rodata
.LCPI0_0:
    .quad   4607182418800017408     # double 1
.LCPI0_1:
    .quad   4611686018427387904     # double 2

.text
main:                                   # @main
    push    rax                  # align the stack by 16 before a call
    movsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0] # xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    movsd   xmm1, qword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_1] # xmm1 = mem[0],zero
    mov     edi, 123
    mov     al, 2                # leave the rest of RAX unmodified
    call    foo
    xor     eax, eax             # return 0
    pop     rcx
    ret
```

GCC emits basically the same thing, but with

```
 ## gcc8.2 -O3
    ...
    mov     eax, 2               # AL = RAX = 2   FP args in regs
    mov     edi, 123
    call    foo
    ...
```

**`mov eax,2` instead of `mov al,2` avoids a false dependency on the old value of RAX, on CPUs that don't rename AL separately from the rest of RAX**.  (Only Intel P6-family and Sandybridge do that, not IvyBridge and later.  And not any AMD CPUs, or Pentium 4, or Silvermont.)

See [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to) for more about how IvB and later are different from Core2 / Nehalem.