# Copying of array to stack

Tags: arrays, assembly, att, stack-memory

I'm a new to assembly and have no idea why It does not `push %EAX` after `end_while:` instruction.
I have to provide the implementation of the function with an example of a call to set the value of the largest 32-bit integer values in the array. A copy of the array (the values of all elements) and the result (the largest value) are passed through the stack.

```
.globl _start
.data
tab: .long 2, 100, 14, 3, 4, 2, 7 
end_tab:
    .equ tab_byte, end_tab - tab
    .equ tab_size, tab_byte/4
.text
prog:
    mov 4(%ESP), %ECX
    mov 8(%ESP), %EBX
    dec %ECX
    push (%EBX, %ECX, 4)
    mov (%EBX, %ECX, 4), %EAX
while:
    dec %ECX
    cmp $0, %ECX 
    jl end_while
    push (%EBX, %ECX, 4)
    cmp (%EBX, %ECX, 4), %EAX
    jl change
    jmp while 
change:
    mov (%EBX,%ECX,4), %EAX
    jmp while
end_while:
    push %EAX
    ret 
_start:
    push $tab
    push $tab_size  
    call prog
    nop
```

As a result I don't get what I expect from this stack meaning that I want to get the largest value following the last element on the stack.

```
0xffffd0e8:     2       100     14      3
0xffffd0f8:     4       2       7       134516786
0xffffd108:     7       134520832       1       -11565
```

Comment: `ret` after `push` seems to be wrong. Note that `ret` is like `pop eip`.

Comment: Related: [What impact could extra push do to assembly program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67368320).  Also Note 1 in this answer on [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/165020) explains a possible calling convention that returns a size after pushing an array, by popping the return address to start with and jumping to it (or push/ret) *after* all the pushes.

Comment: Ok, but how to solve it? When I get rid of ret at all it seems to be working but then there are some addresses on stack:
0xff7fe000:     134520832       100     2       100
0xff7fe010:     14      3       4       2
0xff7fe020:     7       134516785