# In assembly, how to handle Windows API with a return value that's documented as less than native register width?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, x86-64, calling-convention

For many years, [ntohs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-ntohs) (32-bit version) had a return value
that was zero extended into the high 16 bits (word). However, after a recent update of Windows 10, it sometimes returns garbage in the upper word.

For example, passing argument 0xF00D to

```
call        ntohs
```

the return values are

- EAX = 00F00DF0 (32-bit code)
- RAX = 0000000000000DF0 (64-bit code)

The fix in MASM code is to zero extend the return register using [movzx](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movzx) (identical to MSVC)

```
call        ntohs
movzx       eax, ax
```

**Question**

Is it correct that any Windows API with a return value that's documented as less than native register width, there's no guarantee of the upper bits being zeroed out i.e., the return value in RAX = 0000000000000DF0 (64-bit) was most likely coincidental?

Comment: You're talking about C-compatible Windows DLLs, not "all APIs" correct?  C-compatible functions follow the per-platform C ABI.  COM objects have a more complicated binary interface which is also well-defined (and references the C ABI).  WinRT has yet a different binary interface, abstracted through platform-agnostic metadata.  And that doesn't even get into things like .NET which ship with the OS but aren't really OS APIs.

Comment: Who is looking at those upper bits of the return value?  C code appears not to: https://godbolt.org/z/37x96qz37 (it zero extends ax, though why it doesn't just `test ax,ax` I don't know..), so as far as I can tell, it isn't looking at those upper bits.

Comment: MSVC does a [movzx   ecx, ax] so ecx contains the 2 reversed bytes and the upper 16 bits cleared. But, in MASM, I've seen code incorrectly taking eax (instead of ax) by assuming the upper bits were zeroed out.

Comment: For 32 bits, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/argument-passing-and-naming-conventions?view=msvc-160 *seems* to say that "Return values are also widened to 32 bits and returned in the EAX register", which I think would contradict what you observed.  But I'm not so familiar with the many different x86 calling conventions on Windows, so I'm not ready to call this a Windows library bug.

Comment: Note that its quite inefficient to actually set up args and `call ntohs` (and treat the call-clobbered regs as clobbered) when you could just `rol ax, 8` (or `ntohl` -> `bswap eax` or whatever register is convenient).  You're programming in x86 asm and it's a known fact that x86 is little-endian.  That would also solve the zero-extension problem because you can use `movzx` yourself, or for 32-bit, writing a 32-bit register guarantees zero-extension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least for x64, the upper bits are undefined and the caller is responsible for doing zero- or sign-extension if needed.  If your code relied on upper bits being zero, I'm afraid it was buggy all along, and you have just been lucky until now.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160

> The state of unused bits in the value returned in RAX or XMM0 is undefined.

Comment: Perfect! "The state of unused bits in the value returned in RAX or XMM0 is undefined." Thanks!

Comment: @vengy: Note that other x86 calling conventions work the same way, such as x86-64 System V, and i386 System V (used non-Windows OSes).  On some other ISAs, like MIPS and PowerPC, args and also return values are expected to be sign-extended to fill a register, I think.  But not on x86 where narrow operand-sizes are available.  (x86-64 SysV has an unofficial extension relied on by clang where [narrow *args* are expected to be extended to 32-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for/36760539#36760539))

Comment: Not zeroing the upper part of EAX is a bad sign for efficiency, presumably meaning it's doing a `mov` to AX [with a false dependency on the old value of EAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers), instead of `movzx`.  Yet another reason to just `rol ax, 16` yourself instead of copying an arg to the stack for a stdcall function!