# C++ parameter passing optimization of trivial classes size

Tags: c++, optimization, clang, compiler-optimization, calling-convention

I have a trivial `struct A` which represents a type-safe wrapper for std::int8_t. `A` has been simplified to represent a minimal reproducible problem.

**For performance reasons** with `-O3` the struct should follow the same optimizations of `std::int8_t` however when passing the struct as a parameter in [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/6P9zGj3W8):

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

using in = std::int8_t;

template<typename T>
struct A {
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto operator +( A <T> lhs, A <T> rhs)
noexcept -> decltype(lhs.value + rhs.value)
{ return lhs.value + rhs.value; }

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto operator -( A <T> lhs, A <T> rhs)
noexcept -> decltype(lhs.value - rhs.value)
{ return lhs.value - rhs.value; }

template <typename T>
inline constexpr auto operator *( A <T> lhs, A <T> rhs)
noexcept -> decltype(lhs.value * rhs.value)
{ return lhs.value * rhs.value; }

auto h(A<in> a, A<in> b){
    return (a*b)*(a-b);
}

auto g(in a, in b){
    return (a*b)*(a-b);
}
```

the function (which I called `h(A<std::int8_t>, A<std::int8_t>)` contains an overhead of two `movsx`  compared to the function `g(std::int8_t, std::int8_t)`:

```
h(A<signed char>, A<signed char>):                            
        movsx   eax, dil  <-- diff
        movsx   ecx, sil  <-- diff
        mov     edx, ecx
        imul    edx, eax
        sub     eax, ecx
        imul    eax, edx
        ret
g(signed char, signed char):                                  
        mov     eax, esi
        imul    eax, edi
        sub     edi, esi
        imul    eax, edi
        ret
```

- Is the problem related to some struct space constraint of standard C++? Please explain the theory behind
- Provide (if exists) a portable/compiler-specific way to optimize `A`.

**Note: h == g for every std::int*_t != (std::int8_t or std::int16_t) (i.e. std::int32_t, std::int64_t)**

Comment: Please make your questions self-contained, without the need for links to external sites. Copy-paste your [mre] into the question itself.

Comment: I don't see the equivalence for 16 bit integers

Comment: I doubt the macro makes the code shorter. I had to use `-E` to see the actual code. Why do you not show the actual code generated from the macro?

Comment: Clang use an undocumented extension to the x86-64 System V calling convention where narrow integer args are extended to 32-bit.  Apparently this only applies to primitive types, not struct wrappers.  GCC makes function calls compatible with this, but doesn't *depend* on it for incoming args: it would use `movsx` for both functions.  See [Is a sign or zero extension required when adding a 32bit offset to a pointer for the x86-64 ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36706721)

Comment: it is on purpose that eg `A<T> + A<T>` returns `T` ? (Also not obvious with the macro, naively I expected `A<T>` return type)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/ssYqrhr1n shows AArch64 clang having to use `sxtb` for both versions, so this calling-convention extension seems to be target-specific.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai: Isn't the return type just `auto`, from `return lhs.value op rhs.value`?  For narrow `T`, implicit integer promotion means they return `int`.  If we explicitly use a return type of `int8_t` for `h()`, clang is smart enough to optimize away the sign-extension (https://godbolt.org/z/fx5caz3b1) since the low bits of the final result don't depend on high bits of any temporaries.  ([Which 2's complement integer operations can be used without zeroing high bits in the inputs, if only the low part of the result is wanted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34377711))

Answer (score 3):

Clang use an undocumented extension to the x86-64 System V calling convention where narrow integer args are extended to 32-bit. Apparently this only applies to primitive types, not struct wrappers. GCC makes function calls compatible with this, but doesn't depend on it for incoming args: it would use `movsx` for both functions. See *[Is a sign or zero extension required when adding a 32bit offset to a pointer for the x86-64 ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for)*

https://godbolt.org/z/ssYqrhr1n shows AArch64 clang having to use `sxtb` for both versions, so this calling-convention extension seems to be target-specific.

**Your functions return `int`** (because you use an `auto` return type and narrow `T` has implicit integer promotion to `int`).  Sign-extension of `int8_t` inputs is necessary to get the correct `int` result from operations on the promoted values, if the inputs weren't already guaranteed to be sign-extended to `int` width.

If you make `h()` or `g()` return `int8_t`, clang is smart enough to optimize away the sign-extension because it knows that the low bits of operations like `add`/`sub`/`mul` don't depend on higher bits of temporaries; only things like division and right shift do that.  (*[Is a sign or zero extension required when adding a 32bit offset to a pointer for the x86-64 ABI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706721/is-a-sign-or-zero-extension-required-when-adding-a-32bit-offset-to-a-pointer-for)*)

```
int8_t h(A<in> a, A<in> b){
    return (a*b)*(a-b);
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCBmABykAA6oCoRODB7evnrJqY4CQSHhLFEx8baY9vkMQgRMxASZPn5cFVXptfUEhWGR0bEArLZ1DU3ZrQoj3cG9Jf1mAwCUtqhexMjsHOYAzMHI3lgA1CbbbsiT%2BIIn2CYaAIK3d4fHZttYNCGHAPLKAPoAKtgALLKAJ3QEQVCJUiHTCqRJkQ7ETAENYMbDwxEACUWxwGbkezwImBYiQMxOOpwIAE9EoxWJhDv9rniCfdnsFaDNDmgGJM4QjDkwvERDlDokwiMQxYkIKzCc9FVjKW5mdtsIdaAgFDDlSdVSziNrcQxUHCNokCIcALSGlFojGCkwAdgs8vutwAnALiCZ8QqXQARR4B17vbk/SGJXF%2BtlPb5/QEgsEQqEw5Go4gMTXagB0ADcxF5GVCkXnC95MCc3bGFYr6w2YVh9jS6RAtQoC0WS4ky52K8Xloc7osQ/cvKkjIdgpTA4cLiAQMECHFfgRq2O7sTSeSq1TafS2Ezro9JsQvA5h8dXXWmYcB3urB7ncHtk%2BHuyExBrKPP5Hrb%2B8aRgAVIBjzLquVoIBADynMELJMDCsFuPB6qHBEo43p%2BzwZmihwQEwwEYcBBHWhhG7PsGHr3MKorABAM6IdO2bkVh8Y4faWb4YRxGkeRb4hi%2BHDLLQnADLwfgcFopCoJwBKWNY86rOsjI7DwpAEJownLAA1iAkjOrmXAAGyes6zqvHEXDbBoxkDHExn6Jwki8CwEgaBopCSdJskcLwCggJ5mlScJpBwLAMCICgqCknQ0TkJQaCxfQMT1Cw%2BZxNa%2ByGMAXDOhorRYPmeAbAAangmAAO5fHSknqTQtDEsQAUQBEWmkBEwT1NSnDqZ1zDENSXwRNomAOL1vBJWwghfAwtA9SFpBYBEXjAG4Yi0AF3C8FgLA5eIi34MiDh4PmmBbdJcJjSKmzqculTtVyETEN1HhYBNGnEHgbnbcsVAGMACjlVVNWMB9/CCCIYjsFIMiCIoKjqItuitAYRgoNY1j6HgEQBZAyxQtUW3WhcJyBqYCmWK8NpfNsNoAOobbwqBncQX1YHjEDLHYY3VC4DDuJ4zT%2BALPTFKUOQpGkAhjC0SRS9UYt9DEEyVLzHRTLLeg8ydAidA0StzCrwxdFrExTIbEtcNzykbBIIliRJ7W%2BUKxDpZlTA8mjwCHHluYaEZ%2BG4IQJAvNs1u8MFWiLLpIADGYuZxDZZhmM6xlcA5nrbAMtlORwLmkG5Bm5p6nr2XEnoeTZScLF5zucP5gUaVpyzhVFSWJHFZAUBAHddyg3t5QVS2YMVZUVdVtXg3QTUtW1i39d1H2L4Nw2jeN22kFNjAELN83tctq3rbQm0fbt%2B2bNJR3q2dF28FdyA3R992iYtT0vYNb23ZHX0/Twf0AyBhPUGdVeAQ2EKIcQsNwEIzUO1XQZh9A5QxpTGwT1OYE0tOkYmpNtjk0xlTOm1paYMyZjJVm7NzrwG5mrXWfgICuDNqQQIMxxb9GdPLPI6QmG5GlgwS27C2jqz1prIW4whF0P1tMIoyttaiKyHLSYXQBEqxtmsO21s87iTrotF2qgHLWmMpIL2OVfaGQDlwIO%2BApRhwjs3EKMc84FzcvHf2GhJBcC4BoUupkTLOiGN5ZmDdbBNyjtpUgelXFJw0CnNOGdTLZ1zq/bYTtdHBLCY41%2BZhUk%2BXSS3ZYrNUjOEkEAA)

```
// x86-64 clang 17 -O3
h(A<signed char>, A<signed char>):
        mov     eax, esi
        mul     dil
        sub     dil, sil
        mul     dil
        ret
```

```
// AArch64 clang
h(A<signed char>, A<signed char>):
        mul     w8, w1, w0
        sub     w9, w0, w1
        mul     w0, w8, w9
        ret
```

---

As @463035818_is_not_an_ai points out, **you might actually want to have your template functions return `A<T>`** instead of just `T` or `int`; that would also avoid the need for sign-extension.

Comment: I am aware that `h` returns `int` instead of `T` or `A<T>`: I was more concerned about a solution for the performance penalty without changing the function type

Comment: @resu: Usually inlining makes arg-passing overhead small compared to the amount of work in function bodies. If these types aren't visible at ABI boundaries (between a shared library and an application using it), hopefully LTO can avoid having too many non-inline function calls in hot paths.  The actual template functions themselves will always inline, but your `h()` is still tiny and should only be used in places it can inline.

Comment: @resu:  I don't know what the rules are for the undocumented extension to the x86-64 SysV calling convention, like perhaps a `union { int8_t; A<int8_t>; };` would be worth trying?  Or pass the args as `int` so the caller is required to have them already sign-extended, but has to explicitly specify the template?  That isn't helpful for operator overloads.  Or `union { int; A<int8_t>; }` perhaps?  IDK if anything like that would be acceptable in your real use case or totally defeat the purpose of what you're doing, so I haven't tried these wild guesses.

Comment: "IDK if anything like that would be acceptable in your real use case..." I think it would not be acceptable